# Can we get the application name from the socket address?

Tags: linux, sockets, websocket

Can we find name of the application which is running on a given socket address?

By socket address, I mean the combination of IP Address and Port Number.

Like we can find out the name of the host from the IP address by using the following command in linux:

> host [IP]

But is there any command or any way to find out the application name in the same manner as we can find the hostname?

If we can find out only web-application names or tomcat service name, then it is also fine.

Comment: If you're talking about trying to do this from a remote computer, then NO you cannot do that.   If you know it's a web server, then you could make a web request to it and see if there is any identifying information that comes back in the headers, but other than that, you can't query process information remotely without setting up an app on the target computer that would query that info locally and then send it back to you.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I am trying to do this from a remote computer, but I have sudo access as root on all the servers whose socket addresses are provided to find the application names.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly easy way to do this is to use "netstat":

```
gruescher@SMARTBUILD:~$ sudo netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      712/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1217/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      928/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1487/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25654/postgres
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19660/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:513             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      980/xinetd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      980/xinetd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19660/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41516           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31353/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      712/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2757/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::24693                :::*                    LISTEN      13707/fo_scheduler
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      928/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1487/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      19660/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::48611                :::*                    LISTEN      31353/rpc.statd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      19660/smbd
```

As you can see, it displays port, local address, PID and process name.

You have to run this as superuser.